# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception (Flutter)

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

I tried to run my flutter app after reinstalling my dart SDK and it's been giving this error despite being connected to the internet. I've had this issue for a long while now. I have tried removing 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' but it didn't seem to have an effect. I am at a loss.
I have tried flutter clean, changing the channel from beta to stable back to beta and stable again, reinstalling sdk with api level 28. And all of this started after some issue I had with using the Animator widget, something about blocs.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :google_sign_in
         project :app > project :firebase_storage
         project :app > project :google_api_availability
         project :app > project :sqflite
         project :app > project :geolocator
         project :app > project :firebase_messaging
         project :app > project :path_provider
         project :app > project :cloud_firestore
         project :app > project :location_permissions
         project :app > project :image_picker
         project :app > project :firebase_auth
         project :app > project :firebase_core
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > URI does not specify a valid host name: https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > URI does not specify a valid host name: https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > URI does not specify a valid host name: https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > URI does not specify a valid host name: https:/maven.google.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4229bfbbae455ad69c967be19aee3fadd6486e1.pom'.
               > Connection reset

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the vanilla Dart SDK is being used as opposed to the one that's shipped with Flutter.

One simple fix would be to get rid of the Dart SDK that you installed and reinstall Flutter.

Alternatively, fixing the PATH environment variable would ensure the SDK that's used.

Comment: Great, consider accepting the answer as it would also help others.